# Redirect to another website using wordpress and querystring

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, wordpress

I am new to WordPress and want to redirect some specific traffic. Here's an example -

1. A user from a different website clicks on a link with url `http://mywordpresssite.com/redirect?url=http://amazon.in/blablabla`
2. I want my website to redirect the request to 
      `http://amazon.in/blablabla` or whatever be the url in the querystring without loading anypage of my website.
3. My website should function normally for all other requests.

I tried with htaccess and came up with this -

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)url=([^&]+)(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1 [R=302,L]
```

But the RewriteRule results in `http://mywordpresssite.com/http://amazon.in/blablabla?url=http://amazon.in/blablabla` which is wrong.

I am new to htaccess and would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Can't you just use `wp_redirect()` rather than .htaccess?

Comment: @mevius Can you tell me how to do this using wp_redirect()?

Comment: @mevius He doesnt want the website to load any pages, as he stated in number 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following in .htaccess in the root of your site. Note that this should go before your existing WordPress mod_rewrite rules but after `RewriteEngine On`.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^url=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^redirect$ %1 [R=302,QSD,L]
```

The `%1` refers to the first parenthesised subpattern in the `RewriteCond` directive (ie. everything after the "url=").

The `QSD` flag (Apache 2.4+) removes the query string from the original request.

Before Apache 2.4 you would need to change the `RewriteRule` to read (note the additional `?` at the end of the substitution):

```
RewriteRule ^redirect$ %1? [R=302,L]
```

Comment: Thanks but this fails on http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ with output url = 
`http://mywordpresssite.com/http://amazon.in/blablabla?url=http://amazon.in/blablabla`

Comment: `htaccess.madewithlove.be` is a nice tool, but it's not perfect (I have sent a couple of bug reports myself in the past). The "tool" would seem to be incorrect in this instance - there's no way you could get that URL from the above directives (with the `QSD` flag). I have tested those directives and it seems to work OK on my test server. However, this does require Apache 2.4 (the `QSD` is only available from Apache 2.4+)

Comment: I've updated my answer if you are running this on < Apache 2.4 - if you try this version in the "tool" you get something a little better (no query string). However, the "tool" is assuming that the `RewriteRule` substitution is relative, but it is not. The "tool" does not appear to use a real Apache/mod_rewrite engine - they seem to have written their own interpreter?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^redirect$ %1? [R=302,L,NC,NE]`

I used this to make it work with encoded URL's

Comment: Minor point, only use the `NC` flag if you specifically want a case insensitive match, (ie. "Redirect", "reDiRect", "REDIRECT", etc.) - it's often overused.